# New enrolment method is not working properly in Totara (Moodle)

Tags: moodle, totara

I am trying to add a new custom enrolment method to a base Totara (Moodle) installation. I decided to copy the existing "Self enrolment" enrolment method, because it is relatively simple and therefore seemed to be a good starting point for my custom method.

I changed the name and all of the references to the "Self enrolment" method to my new method name. This seemed to have worked because when I logged into the Totara dashboard I got the popup for a new plugin installation.

I went through the installation process and didn't run into any errors. Next I activated my plugin in the "Enrolment plugin" menu. Everything seemed fine until I tried to add my new method to a course.

Firstly the new method should be displayed bij default on the "Enrolment methods" page of the course but it isn't, however I can select it with the dropdown located below. When I do I am redirected to the config page of the enrolment method, so far so good. But when I click the button on the bottom of the page to add the method to the course it still isn't visible on the "Enrolment methods" page of the course.

When I log in as a regular user I can't access the course through my new method, so the method and the course haven't been properly linked. However when I look in the database I do see that my new method has been added to the course in the enrol table.

The problem doesn't seem to be caching related because I have purged it a couple of times already but the method still won't show up.

I am working with Totara version 16.2 (Moodle 3.4.9)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it seems that the "Self enrolment" plugin uses the get_name() function of the /server/lib/enrollib.php by default. However this function is written in a way to avoid "fancy" plugin names according to a comment in the function. The function explodes your plugin name on "_" and only uses the first part of your name, which means the records in enrol won't be recognised as records of your plugin because the names don't match.

I solved this by adding my own get_name() to my plugin, which returns the whole name.

The function:

```
/**
     * Returns name of this enrol plugin
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_name() {
        // second word in class is always enrol name, sorry, no fancy plugin names with _
        $words = explode('_', get_class($this));
        return $words[1];
    }
```